# Does Domain Transfer also transfer expiration date?

Tags: domain

I was planning to move my domains from GoDaddy to Gandi but on Gandi's transfer checkout it asked me to pay domain for 1 year but the domain that I want to transfer out from GoDaddy is expiring in 2.5 years. 
Do I loose those 2.5 years if I transfer domain now or is it going to give me 1 year extra?

Comment: Guess gandi aren't going to support your domain for 2.5 years for free.

Comment: @Sandman4 They are required to by ICANN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the existing registration period is retained. Your domain will be valid for 3.5 years when you transfer.

Comment: I thought so. After all, it is ICANN not GoDaddy that that holds the expiration (I think).